# What is the server in context of server side rendering(SSR)?

Tags: next.js

I'm new to frontend development learning Next.js, and I recently learned about SSR.
To me, the word, 'server', is somehow difficult to understand.

I know that CSR, typical architecture that client requests specific API and server handles that request and send response, then client handles that response. That interaction occurs every time user requests.

Then SSR, I learned that server pre-renders the whole page including handle api and send completed html to web browser(client). But it does not occur in build phase. If it occurs in build phase, it is statically generated page.

At this point, I can't fully understand what is the server and where is the server. I think that someone(or something) must handle API requests like browser in CSR. But statically hosted pages can't handle that (I think).

Is there any wrong with my thought or how can I understand it?
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words `server` is the system where your web application is hosted.

In context to SSR it refers to computer or machine that generates the fully rendered HTML for a web page for the client(Browser) to consume.

It can be seen as Server is Producer and Client is the Consumer, when client seeks data from the server through API calls